# assigned enum value doesn't change

Tags: swift, enums, sprite-kit

I have a Player class which has an enum for changing the Player type. See init below.

```
init(playerType: PlayerType) {
    self.playerType = playerType
    spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: playerType.simpleDescription())
    sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: spriteTexture)
    sprite.name = playerCategoryName
    sprite.zPosition = 10
}
```

In the `GameScene` I change some player properties using the following method, but the enum value for `player.playerType` doesn't change when assigned. What is cause and how can I correct this?

```
func changePlayer (newPlayerType:Player.PlayerType) {
    player.spriteTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: newPlayerType.simpleDescription())
    let action = SKAction.setTexture(player.spriteTexture)
    player.sprite.runAction(action)
    player.playerType == newPlayerType //this doesn't seem to work, player.playerType remains unchanged every time

    println("raw value of newPlayerType is \(newPlayerType.rawValue)")
    println("raw value of player.playerType is \(player.playerType.rawValue)")

}
```

Comment: what is `player`? You're referring to something whose declaration you don't show. Show it. It's crucial. Also, what is PlayerType? Come on, if you want help, show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a different case to an existing enum; you can make an existing enum change its own case, but not by assigning into it.

You can replace an enum instance (with one case) by another enum instance (with a different case) of the same enum, but only if the enum is a `var` reference, not a `let` reference.

Comment: thanks, I painfully burnt my whole evening over this one.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Since you never showed your code, I still don't know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the equality operator.

You're looking for `=` for assignment (note, only one equals sign).

Comment: I tried using `=` but I get an error - `Cannot assign to 'playerType' in 'player'`

Answer (score 0):

Check your enum reference it should be var not let